# Harmonic wave (infinite length and duration)

Tags: waves, wavelength, harmonics

I am not sure why a harmonic wave is said to have infinite length and duration.

I found this image, but I am not sure I have really understood it.

[image]

Here, there are three waves: the first one is a harmonic wave, the second and the third ones are wave packets.

Comment: Is your confusion about what the precise definition of wave packet is? What it means for it to be localized?

Comment: I am not sure why a harmonic wave has infinite length and duration.

Comment: Only a small section of the complete wave is shown in the first diagram. The complete harmonic wave actually extends infinitely far to the right and the left. Obviously this is an idealisation of a wave and will not actually occur in real life.

Comment: Who says it has "infinite length and duration."? Why is "infinite" even a concern?

Comment: Like *many* concepts in physics, the "infinite" extension of a sine wave is a first-order model to simplify basic analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the wave which can be qualified as harmonic or not.

A harmonic oscillator is a linear system, whose solutions can be waves of the form:

$$
u(x,t) = A \sin (kx - \omega t + \phi)
$$

but this is a consequence of the force having an expression of the kind:

$$
F = -k x
$$

A force of that sort is not dissipative, therefore the physical system will go on forever (ideally) with a periodic shape: $f(t + T) = f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

A harmonic wave is something like

$$
u(x,t) = A \cos (kx - \omega t + \phi)
$$

So if you fix the time you see

$$
u(x,t_0) = A \cos (kx - \text{constant})
$$

which is oscillating for all space. No matter how far in $x$ you go, it always oscillates between $-A$ and $A$. That is what the first picture is showing. The space between peaks being labeled with $\lambda$.

But that is not realistic for a wave to be spread over infinite length. It is a good first approximation when the size is so big that you might as well treat it as infinite. It is also a much easier formula for $u(x,t)$.

But the next two illustrations seem to be illustrative of a Gaussian wave packet.

$$
u(x,t) = A e^{-(x-ct)^2} \cos (k x - \omega t + \phi)
$$

Again if you fix the time you get

$$
u(x,t_0) = A e^{- (x - ct_0)^2} \cos (kx - \text{constant2})
$$

Now you notice that if you let $x$ go far above or below $ct_0$, you get a factor of $e$ raised to a very negative number as a prefactor. That makes $u(x,t_0)$ in those places close to $0$. That is the second picture. Close to $ct_0$, the $e^{- (x - ct_0)^2}$ is close to $1$ so it looks like the harmonic wave picture above with a corresponding $\lambda$ giving the distance between peaks. But the $\Delta x$ is showing how far above and below $ct_0$ you have to get before $u(x,t_0)$ goes towards $0$.

The third picture is when you fix the point in space and see a function of time. The same sort of math holds but now instead of getting a $\lambda$ describing a distance between peaks you get a $T$ describing time between peaks. And instead of $\Delta x$ describing how far until $u(x,t_0)$ is close to $0$, you have a $\Delta t$ describing how long until $u(x_0,t)$ is close to $0$.

Comment: So if we consider a harmonic wave, is it said to have infinite length and duration if it goes from -oo to +oo in the time and space domains?

Comment: So does it not matter if the wavelength and period of the wave are finite?